# Apache crashes running the controller's index page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cakephp

I'm trying CakePHP for the first time so I'm trying to run the blog tutorial located on CakePHP's website ([Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html)). My CakePHP is installed correctly because when run the index page I get everything in green. But when I added my first controller, model and view and ran the index function of my controller, Apache crashes and I cannot continue.

I have already created the database called "blog" on my MySql.

This is my model class: (located in app/Model/Post.php)

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
}
```

This is my controller: (located at app/Controller/PostsController.php)

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
}
```

And this is my view: (located at app/View/Posts/index.ctp)

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/index.ctp -->

<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
</table>
```

This is the url I'm trying to run:

http://[lclhost]/blog/posts/

And http://[lclhost]/blog/ gives the correct output of the main CakePhp page.

This is the Apache error log I get:

```
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:28 2013] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:34 2013] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:34 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:34 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:35 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:35 2013] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:35 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 10516
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:35 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:35 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:36 2013] [notice] Child 10516: Child process is running
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:36 2013] [notice] Child 10516: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:36 2013] [notice] Child 10516: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:36 2013] [notice] Child 10516: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Mon Sep 09 17:32:36 2013] [notice] Child 10516: Starting thread to listen on port 81.
```

OS: Windows 7

Apache/2.2.11 (Win32)

PHP Version 5.2.8

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "_Apache crashes and I cannot continue_" what exactly do you see? Check Apache's error log to learn more. If Apache crashes you might have found a bug in PHP. What OS are you using and what version of Apache?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen sorry. Updates with the error log.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I'm using Win7, Apache/2.2.11 (Win32)

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477` and try solutions you find.

A common one seems to be copying some `.dll` files.

I've personally run into a segfault myself that I have not found a solution for (tried everything). I think it's something to do with regular expressions. In any case. PHP on Apache/Windows is kinda wonky. Consider switching to Linux if you can't figure it out, it runs much more stable.

Comment: Could we find a more specific solution for this other than "copying some dll files" or "switching to Linux" please?

Comment: I don't have access to your machine, so no. `3221225477` is the generic code for a segfault.